# Interpret text file with some hex codes?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I have a file with contents looking like `PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000!\u0000À¸<91><91>¢\u0001`.

However, I have a different version of the same file looking like `PK^C^D^T^@^F^@^H^@^@^@!^@À¸<91><91>¢^A`

I would like to "interpret" the first file, so that hex codes (6 characters each, including `\u`) get resolved to actual characters. However, as you see, the file is not really binary, but rather contains text representation of some hex codes (as well as some interpreted ones, like `!` etc.)

I thought about using `xxd -r`, with just a few obviously wrong characters as a result. How can I convert my 1st file so that it resembles the 2nd version of it?

Comment: This looks very much like the first few bytes of a zip file. Give it a `.zip` extension and then try to open it.

Comment: It is, in fact, intended to be a .zip file. However, because of how it is currently written (bytes representing characters like `\u0000` rather than `0`), just changing the extension does not work.

Comment: OK, I see. But what about the other characters, i.e. `À,<91>` etc? Are those straight UTF8 characters? (And why would anyone write a zipfile this way?)

Comment: Receiving a zipfile via wire, where it was uploaded to the browser and the browser just sends it to me. Those characters when checked in Vim has hex representation as I would expect them (ex. `À` is `00c0`, as expected.)